# Ubuntu 18.04 logs out unexpectedly or crashes

Tags: gnome, suspend, crash, logout

This problem is going on for several months.

When you try to run a GUI program it suddenly exits the session gets back to the login screen where I get this notification (bubble for several seconds) at the top of screen:

> Automatic suspend.
>   Computer will be suspend very soon due to inactivity.

I've disabled automatic suspend in the power settings.

When returning from hibernation and again trying to run a GUI program the exit symptom is a strange string of "@^"s in top left of the brownish pre-login screen , then the PC becomes unresponsive (no tty's whatsoever) and the only way of closing it is hard reset

My machine is an HP Spectre x360 with dual-boot (with Windows 10 using GRUB)
I use communitheme on GNOME shell v3.28.2

It doesn't happen immediately or when running a specific program, so I cannot "produce" this error at will. I can run 10 or more programs for an hour or so until it strikes.

Where should I start to debugging this problem ?

Help is much needed here

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the part of the /var/log/syslog around the time when the error occured?

Comment: @BernardWei I've disabled communitheme and there was a kernel update , so currently there are no crashes. I'll see how it goes and update if needed. Does it keeps the previous logs after session logout or restart or overruns them ? Thanks

Comment: It does but you have to try to locate the problem areas of the log, which may or may not be easy. E.g., if the crash happens and nothing logged, you could keep searching and not find anything in the log. Or if you may have just missed it and thought there aren't any error logged. Best to wait for the crash to happen then check the logs.

Comment: UPDATE: the bug doesn't exist anymore. Possible solutions: update the kernel (currently I'm on 4.15.0-32-generic) , create a a swap partition instead of a swap file as I've explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064122/690957)