# Resume after Hibernate with Ubuntu 18.04 with HP Probook

Tags: 18.04, hibernate, resume

**My computer**

I have a [HP Probook 650G1](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04029874) notebook, that I have never managed to hibernate with Linux.

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 with a dedicated swap partition (8.25 Gb), bigger than the installed RAM (8 Gb).  No other operating systems are installed.

**The problem**

With any of these commands:

- `sudo pm-hibernate`
- `sudo systemctl hibernate`

my computer switches off correctly.

But when I resume, it does a regular boot.
The command:

```
sudo journalctl -b
```

provides no clues (no special error message).

**Software configuration**

Kernel: `4.15.0-38-generic`

Contents of my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=3197c456-942a-45b2-b8b0-002a81b67e01 /               xfs     defaults        0       0
# /home was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=a2976b22-65d3-46d3-8362-af4c45586937 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=8d41a139-a5ae-4a01-8496-b692ba699f2a none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Contents of `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`:

```
RESUME=UUID=8d41a139-a5ae-4a01-8496-b692ba699f2a
```

If I do this:

```
$ update-initramfs -u -k all
[sudo] senha para david: 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-38-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of uuid=8d41a139-a5ae-4a01-8496-b692ba699f2a
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of uuid=8d41a139-a5ae-4a01-8496-b692ba699f2a
```

I had originally this value:

```
RESUME=UUID=c8ee0bf9-cd8a-4cc2-a6b7-f41e8f5bb71c
```

If I leave the original value again:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-38-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of uuid=8d41a139-a5ae-4a01-8496-b692ba699f2a
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=c8ee0bf9-cd8a-4cc2-a6b7-f41e8f5bb71c
W: but no matching swap device is available.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of uuid=8d41a139-a5ae-4a01-8496-b692ba699f2a
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=c8ee0bf9-cd8a-4cc2-a6b7-f41e8f5bb71c
W: but no matching swap device is available.
```

I **suspect** of this not to be correct.  Maybe another UUID is generated because of cryptsetup.  I don't have enough knowledge.  If I leave the original value, then I see this trace with `journalctl -b` when resuming:

After resuming with original UUID:

```
# journalctl -b | grep swap
Nov 11 09:18:08 halgopotente kernel: zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
Nov 11 09:18:09 halgopotente systemd[1]: Starting Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1...
Nov 11 09:18:09 halgopotente mkswap[1038]: Setting up swap space version 1, size = 8,3 GiB (8854695936 bytes)
Nov 11 09:18:09 halgopotente mkswap[1038]: no label, UUID=ab5d2151-132e-4359-9c2c-7c564792365e
Nov 11 09:18:09 halgopotente systemd[1]: Started Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1.
Nov 11 09:18:09 halgopotente systemd[1]: Found device /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.
Nov 11 09:18:09 halgopotente systemd[1]: Activating swap /dev/mapper/cryptswap1...
Nov 11 09:18:09 halgopotente kernel: Adding 8647164k swap on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:8647164k SSFS
Nov 11 09:18:09 halgopotente systemd[1]: Activated swap /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.
```

Contents of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/themes/breeze/theme.txt

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=uuid=8d41a139-a5ae-4a01-8496-b692ba699f2a"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"
```

My Bios is configured to UEFI Hybrid.
I've tried also the legacy mode, but hibernation still doesn't work.

**Test**

I'm not able to try tuxonice because it isn't yet available for Ubuntu 18.04.

**Related questions**

- [Cannot resume after hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999657/cannot-resume-after-hibernate)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate
- https://superuser.com/questions/383140/linux-grub2-how-to-resume-from-hibernation

I'll be happy to include more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have installed the package `hibernate`, I can hibernate/resume, even though I have to wait some minutes before being able to use my computer after resuming.

```
 apt install hibernate
```

Apart from having modified `/etc/default/grub`.

Other people have [solved hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106113/cant-get-hibernate-to-work-on-ubuntu-18-04) like this.