# Can't get hibernate to work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, swap, hibernate

I can't get Hibernate to work on Ubuntu 18.04, I tried following these tutorials and after all the steps below hibernate still acts as a normal reboot.:

[Github - gnome-shell-extension-hibernate-status](https://github.com/arelange/gnome-shell-extension-hibernate-status)

[Askubuntu: Hibernation in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053134/hibernation-in-18-04)

**System:**

ASUS N580VD with 16GB of ram and 20GB swap

**Partition table:**

```
sda     238,5G  
├─sda1    499M  Windows recovery 
├─sda2    100M  EFI System
├─sda3     16M  Microsoft reserved
├─sda4  117,9G  Microsoft basic data
├─sda5     20G  Linux swap
└─sda6    100G  Linux filesystem
```

**Swap partition UUID:**

```
sudo blkid | grep sda5
/dev/sda5: TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="8d0c9f85-0436-48b5-8973-6aec3b8e3445"
```

**Content of /etc/fstab:**

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=27ed4a93-0aa1-d401-206c-4a930aa1d401 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
/dev/sda5       none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D4A10A933D25B0 /mnt/01D4A10A933D25B0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/864A-6441 /mnt/864A-6441 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0

# Entry for Swap (added for hibernate): 
UUID=8d0c9f85-0436-48b5-8973-6aec3b8e3445 none  swap    sw              0       0
```

**Contents of /etc/default/grub:**

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="2"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=8d0c9f85-0436-48b5-8973-6aec3b8e3445"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="white/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-blue/black"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
```

**Contents of /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla:**

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes

[Enable hibernate to be run via cron]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
```

**Content of /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume:**

```
resume=UUID=8d0c9f85-0436-48b5-8973-6aec3b8e3445
```

**Did these commands:**

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo update-grub
```

I also installed gnome-shell-extension-hibernate-status. Any help would really be apreciated!

EDIT 1: Not only doesn't hibernate work, also my boot time from cold boot became incredibly slow!!

Comment: There is no need to add Solved in the title. Just accept the answer which solved the problem (after 2 days of posting the question if answered by you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a package that you can use easily to hibernate,
open the terminal and write    `sudo apt install hibernate`    , it will ask you some questions and then you can hibernate using `sudo hibernate`

Comment: Haha, thanks for letting me know! I'll remember for the future! It's working now, and if it aint broke don't fix it!

Comment: Is there a way to get the system to lock upon hibernation as well? This is the only method to hibernate I've found that works, but it leaves the computer insecure since it doesn't require a password to log back in